# Build failed showing error "Attribute "android:focusable" was already specified for element "EditText"

Tags: android, build

my code is not being build when trying to run it on device or emulator
with the error 
Error:Attribute "android:focusable" was already specified for element "EditText".
but it gradle build is successful.

i don't what is the problem with it.

Comment: Show xml file..

Comment: post your xml please.

Comment: this error is not tracing to any xml  file

Comment: Your problem is on your layout xml. We need to check your layout xml.

Answer (score 0):

Search in Project using Ctrl + Shift + F(Android Studio) for `android:focusable` and check whether you have put focusable property more than one time in any EditText, just remove that duplicate occurrence of `focusable` property.

Let me know if any other error.